# Is there a way to use a fixture within Patch decorator in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch, fixtures

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def data():
    return "some data"
```

test_fn1.py - The below doesn't work as 'data' fixture can't be resolved when used within patch decorator.

```
@patch("a.b.c.xyz.get_data", new=mock.Mock(return_value=data))
def test_fn1():
   ...
```

I'm aware that I can do something like below.

```
@patch("a.b.c.xyz.get_data")
def test_fn1(get_data_mock, data):
   get_data_mock.return_value = data
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the package [lazy_fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/)

> pip install pytest-lazy-fixture

```
@patch("a.b.c.xyz.get_data", new=mock.Mock(return_value=lazy_fixture("data"))
def test_fn1():
    ...
```